# Примеры сайтов на Laravel для практики

Tags: laravel

Где мне найти примеры сайтов на Laravel для практики, что бы сразу рабочий сайт и github с примером кода? Дайте посмотреть свой код, если можно!?

Answer (score 1):

Можно искать типовые задачи в гугле, например: "laravel user dashboard" и так далее. В результатах выдачи смотреть, где идет ссылка на github репозиторий. Второй способ - https://madewithlaravel.com/ Смотреть что интересует, так же ревьювить код в github пробовать самому.
Искать готовый сайт глупо - любой сайт это набор типовых решений как минимум на половину.
Вопросы в духе как лучше реализовать то или это - вопрос конкретных случаев и практики с инструментом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой репозиторий [Awesome Laravel](https://github.com/chiraggude/awesome-laravel), там в принципе много какой инфы собрано, а скорее ссылок на полезные пакеты и репозитории, книги, видео и так далее.

Можно непосредственно посмотреть на секцию [Code for Reference](https://github.com/chiraggude/awesome-laravel#codebases-for-reference) там будут примеры в том числе работающих сайтов, например [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/).